# How can I avoid exceeding maximum recursion depth when generating a Hadamard Matrix?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, math

I am trying to recursively generate [Hadamard matrices by Sylvester construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walsh_matrix), following this recurrence formula:

```
H(2) = (1  1)
       (1 -1)

H(2**k) = ( H(2**(k-1))   H(2**(k-1)) )
          ( H(2**(k-1))  -H(2**(k-1)) )
```

[this formula as an image of LaTeX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bw126.png)

Or using the notation `(x)` for [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product):

```
H(2**k)  =  H(2)  (x)  H(2**(k-1))
```

My code to generate a Hadamard matrix by Sylvester construction is as follows:

```
def deepMap(f,seq):
    if seq == []:
        return seq
    elif type(seq) != list:
        return f(seq)
    else:
        return [deepMap(f,seq[0])] + deepMap(f,seq[1:])

def Hadamard(n): #n is a power of 2
    if n == 1:
        return [1]
    elif n == 2:
        return [[1,1],[1,-1]]
    else:    
        k = 2
        array = [Hadamard(k)]
        while k < n:
            k *= 2
            matrix,prev = [],array.pop(0)
            for i in range(k):
                if i < k//2:
                    matrix.append(prev[i]+prev[i])
                else:
                    matrix.append(prev[i%(k//2)]+deepMap(lambda x: -x,prev[i%(k//2)]))
            array.append(matrix)
            #print(f'matrix {k} = {matrix}')
        return array[0]
```

The code works, but is pretty slow, and exceeds maximum depth recursion when n > 1024.

How could I make the code handle larger values of `n`?

*Context: This code was written for a Kattis question* https://open.kattis.com/problems/sylvester

Comment: I suggest replacing `return [deepMap(f,seq[0])] + deepMap(f,seq[1:])` with `return [deepMap(f, x) for x in seq]`. It's a small improvement that will make the code faster and stack up fewer recursive calls.

Comment: But most importantly you should probably try to rewrite the whole Hadamard code using numpy arrays instead of nested python lists. In general, if your data is organized in a "multidimensional rectangular array", such as `[[1,1],[1,-1]]`, as opposed to freely-nested lists, such as `[[1,1],[1]]`, then you should probably use numpy arrays rather than lists.

Comment: What input would one use to test this?

Comment: Hi, this question is dead now, but I have put a bunch of work into it so if you open a new one based just on `Hadamard()` and `deepMap()` demonstrating with an example that `Hadamard(2**10)` throws your error, then it will likely be well received and I will give you the solution I have that does not use recursion at all.

Comment: @Stef thank you for your reply! I have thought about using numpy, but numpy is not allowed for this question in Katti.s

Comment: @JonSG yep sure I will reopen the question! Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: @JonSG I apologise it seems that I am unable to open a new question as there is a limit on the number of questions I can pose. I would need to wait a day before I can pose a new question. I am very interested in your solution that does not involve recursion, and I hope you do not mind waiting.

Comment: It's also possible to reopen this question without creating a new one. We can vote to reopen it, especially if you edit it with @JonSG 's suggestions.

Comment: Am I correct to understand that the Hadamard matrices you're building are exactly the [Walsh matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walsh_matrix)? In which case, please add a sentence in the text of you question to present the recurrence relation that defines them `(H(2) = ... and H(2**k) = ...H(2**k-1)...)` and then no one can complain that the question isn't clear and it will be reopened.

Comment: @Stef yep I am building the Walsh matrices; I have edited the question as per Jon's suggestions. I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: For what it's worth, using numpy, getting hadamard(1024) is immediate: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY9BDsIgEEX3nOLvCglGqa5MepKmi4nSSGKBAI329BWr1trEnwyLeW9g8EO6OLsfxza4Drbv/ADTeRcSKAQaJE7Onihpm4uxs25xo2u8cCuODDlFUVCMfadhYSII3t10gGtRZjQpps2sqqBeE88EnfpgX0/wWjViIvr6Uct/aq2kamQ@N6qZp6L@6oTqsyG2W5RifdHiP3xmz/Al4SRBItfdxEoJ@WOuxc3CXKlTdze3BGM@GJv4e0e1Kw8CYhwf "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: Here is a not-too-smart version without numpy, still much faster than 20 seconds for hadamard(1024): [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZBRa8MgFIXf/RXnLbG1oNmexrI/IlICMdO4maAJZb8@NbZFBrmIeM7n9eCd/xYz@bdt6/WAfp1rw@AYLGcjZ4itoB8EqYYpwMJ6hM5/69o97Rcaj9FeRlp@tkqO/DwqtIg47V4yFCF7qun62j@bqqrqYlx/NTy@WjSwER3m6aYDpgFN4vmeSQ9JyXP2tWR7qg6sR4fkKq1WFCWKEv@YyOzykC5FNfl0M/ZHJ/0JX75YZsaZowe2Y/zYTttFFORwegUFvazBwxAyB@uXOo9I8Oadgm7bHQ "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: Your code, with just my small edit for `deepMap`, now it's fast and no recursion depth exceeded: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVLLboMwELznK7aKqtgNeUB7qKJy76VfgHxwxbqxIMY1tCGK8u3UxiQu5dA9gL07OzNeW5@afaUeuy5HATmifuOaiKjGT7qbgQ0pwG4gTSFjPuPCYPNllKv0KSwtrDlpJK4R7lIoZd1M4KIvDx01TupZMAAtBVEZaEH2Mmw2cw5fec4P3ORE0R3MFcgaOOjqiAYqAcnVsXJ@4yl/zILdHpNMMVkcxSyy31XMWPDqFjdsAekg5oIbw082k93cFZTdqse9LNF2vIAKYp7k4TeLiwNvjGwjbfDb8bGop17rSpMtHSHdbKSbjeHqA63gmHuYg7SqxWaTTItBbc21RpUTJ5pJthz@dNIyvrL/iO6JE6Zseb3Tkh/ecw7tDlb@hAFDx2L@0AOb5x4D5tpI1RCx8EU4Fxc7rrPfXRb07532hNnWviHfGJ5Rsn16pkC77gc)

Comment: @Stef Thank you for your response! I tried it out and now it is faster than before. However, a MemoryError was encountered when I tried the inputs in the Kattis question. I believe that my approach is fundamentally wrong, and I will need to find some other approach to do the Kattis question. Thank you for your help thus far!

Comment: @chiralcentre did you get a MemoryError with my version too (the one with a function called `dup`)?

Comment: @chiralcentre Sooooo I clicked the link and looked at the description of the problem. Look at the sample inputs: `n=268435456 x=12345 y=67890 w=11 h=12`. Surely there's a clever modulo trick to apply here. They want you to return a matrix of size 11x12. You don't need to build the entirety of the huge H(268435456) just to return that small submatrix!!

Comment: @chiralcentre I might be wrong, but I think you can get the number in cell [x,y] of the matrix by examining the binary expansions of x and y and huuuuum something, uh, I'm not quite sure what yet.

Comment: @chiralcentre Alternatively you could do a kind of "binary search" to search for the region defined by x,y,w,h in the huge matrix, and only compute the small submatrix in that region. For instance `solution(16, 9, 10, 2, 3) = - solution(8, 1, 2, 2, 3) = `, because the subregion is entirely contained in the bottomright quadrant of Hadamard(16).

Comment: Continuing, `solution(8, 1, 2, 2, 3) = concatenate(solution(4, 1, 2, 2, 2), solution(4, 1, 0, 1, 1))`

Comment: @Stef yep I was thinking that I dont need to construct the whole of the Hadamard matrix, but I was struggling to find a mathematical relationship between the number at a position and the coordinates of the position. Thank you for your insights!

Comment: @chiralcentre Any progress?

Comment: @Stef hi I have managed to solve it using another set of code; I realised that this code is fundamentally flawed and I coded the solution from scratch again.

Answer (score 1):

### Fixing your code: recursion in `deepMap`

With just a small modification to your `deepMap` function, it becomes faster and avoids stacking up thousands of recursive calls: replace `return [deepMap(f,seq[0])] + deepMap(f,seq[1:])` with `return [deepMap(f, x) for x in seq]`.

```py
def deepMap(f,seq):
    if seq == []:
        return seq
    elif type(seq) != list:
        return f(seq)
    else:
        return [deepMap(f, x) for x in seq]

def Hadamard(n): #n is a power of 2
    if n == 1:
        return [1]
    elif n == 2:
        return [[1,1],[1,-1]]
    else:    
        k = 2
        array = [Hadamard(k)]
        while k < n:
            k *= 2
            matrix,prev = [],array.pop(0)
            for i in range(k):
                if i < k//2:
                    matrix.append(prev[i]+prev[i])
                else:
                    matrix.append(prev[i%(k//2)]+deepMap(lambda x: -x,prev[i%(k//2)]))
            array.append(matrix)
            #print(f'matrix {k} = {matrix}')
        return array[0]

print( Hadamard(2048) ) # should take less than a second
```

#### A different version: avoiding `.append`

Since we already know the size of the matrix, I suggest creating a matrix that already has the correct size, then filling it recursively or iteratively. To fill the matrix, I made a function `dup` that duplicates a quadrant of the matrix to another quadrant.

```py
def dup(h, k, i0,j0, s=1):
    for i in range(k):
        for j in range(k):
            h[i0+i][j0+j] = s * h[i][j]

def had(n):
    '''assume n >= 2 is a power of 2'''
    h = [[0 for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(n)]
    h[0][0]=1
    h[0][1]=1
    h[1][0]=1
    h[1][1]=-1
    k = 2
    while k < n:
        dup(h, k, 0,k)
        dup(h, k, k,0)
        dup(h, k, k,k, -1)
        k *= 2
    return h

print( had(2048) )
```

#### Using `numpy`: everything is easy with `concatenate`

Using numpy.concatenate, the code becomes much shorter, much much faster, and easier to read:

```py
from numpy import array, concatenate

def hadamard(n):
    '''assume n is a power of 2'''
    if n == 1:
        return array([1])
    elif n == 2:
        return array([[1,1],[1,-1]])
    else:
        a = hadamard(n // 2)
        return concatenate(
            (concatenate((a, a), axis=1),
            concatenate((a, -a), axis=1)),
            axis=0
        )

print( hadamard(2048) )
```